# Unable to establish shell with ncat over SSL

Tags: network, windows, linux

I am attempting to get a shell open between a Linux and Windows machine. 
On the Windows machine, I run:

```
ncat --exec cmd.exe -vnl 4444 --ssl
```

Once it is listening, I run the following command on my linux machine:

```
ncat -v x.x.x.x 4444 --ssl
```

After doing so, I receive this error message:

```
Ncat: Failed SSL connection from x.x.x.x: error:1408F10b:SSL routines:SSl3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
```

Linux ncat version is at 7.60 and 5.59BETA1 on Windows. Are these incompatible or is my syntax incorrect?

Comment: The binary on windows uses a OpenSSL 1.0.0 from 2011.  It is probably some incompatible cipher or protocol version - like the old ncat offering SSLv3 which is usually no longer supported by newer version. A packet capture (with tcpdump or wireshark, upload to cloudshark.org) might help to get details about the problem.

Comment: You are correct, it was just an incompatible version of OpenSSL. Thank you!

Comment: @3x14 how did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the Windows Firewall is allowing this connection.

Comment: A firewall would cause "wrong version number"? It seems to me if you get that error, then the connection was made.